# Ag grid: expand/collapse with pagination

Tags: vue.js, ag-grid

I'm using detail-master feature and pagination. When I expend most bottom row, detail grid should stay on the same page as master row. Any good examples on how to do that? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a moderately satisfying solution: This only works if I set paginationPageSize manually; with paginationAutoPageSize=true bottom row expansion still goes to another page.

```
onRowGroupOpened(event) {
        if (event.node.expanded) {
            this.gridOptions.api.paginationSetPageSize(++this.pageSize);
        } else {
            this.gridOptions.api.paginationSetPageSize(--this.pageSize);
        }
    },
```